# Chrome DevTools - idle time and janks

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have this problem: I open some website, open dev tools, go to timeline tab, hit "record", scroll the page to the bottom and that is what I see:
[image]

I mean those frames with janks. I have no idea, why those frames takes more than 30ms, if there are no tasks on timeline? You see - only few thin bars and a lot of free space...

I switch to the waterfall view and..:
[image]

Again - a lot of free space. What can I do to eliminate those janks? I know - it's still around 30fps, but I want to achieve more, especially, that I dont see any expensive task.

Sometimes I dont understand this timeline...

Comment: What is the one red x error?

Comment: When you click to the left of the Yellow box "Timer Fired" record (to expand it), what do you see contained within?

Comment: The error is related to some network issue (403 on some resource).
When I expand "Timer fired" I see few tasks, but they contains within "Timer fired" bar. So I think that is not the problem.